# Failed assertion: line 677 pos 11: 'field == orders[0][0]'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling, inequality

I don't know why I can not access the data from flutter while using two "where". can any help me to solve this? what I want is to get all the documents between a period of time
Error

```
The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([dateEnd]), false]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([date])' when an inequality operator is invoked.
'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 677 pos 11: 'field == orders[0][0]'
```

MY Code

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(widget.collectionDbName)
            .where('dateEnd', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
            .orderBy('dateEnd')
            .where('date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now())
            .orderBy('date', descending: widget.sortingOrderDesc)
            .snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different fields for two where clauses and using <= & >= ranges which are not valid.
As per [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) You can perform range (<, <=, >, >=) or not equals (!=) comparisons only on a single field.
Valid Examples:

```
const q1 = query(citiesRef, where("state", ">=", "CA"), where("state", "<=", "IN"));
const q2 = query(citiesRef, where("state", "==", "CA"), where("population", ">", 1000000));
```